# How big of breaker to use for a 125 amp sub panel

Tags: electrical-panel

I am looking to add a 125-amp sub panel to my house. How big of a breaker would I need in my main panel to feed the sub panel?

Comment: What size wire are you running to your panel?  Are you sure you don't want to get a bigger panel in order to have more spaces, for that matter?  What make and model is your main panel, anyway?

Comment: Depends on how much power you want to use at one time from sub.  It is up to a maximum 125-amp, but can have a less amperage breaker to feed sub panel.  How much is the main breaker in main panel?  Should be less than that one.  Sub panel adds more circuit places, not more power.

Comment: I’m thinking this has been discussed many times and should be closed as a duplicate because there is not enough information, take your pick

Comment: @EdBeal. Yes, this question has been asked and answered so many times here and I've only been around here for about a year and a half. How can we get posters to make just a medocium of effort before just getting lazy and ask us what to.   I vote to close also. +

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wiring size for 100amp sub panel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/104123/wiring-size-for-100amp-sub-panel)

Answer (score 1):

### Breaker size is decided by wire size

You can run any wire size you want. It's OK to supply a 125A panel with less than 125A, as long as the breaker in the main panel protects the wires as follows:

14/3 copper feeder needs a 15A breaker.
12/3 copper requires a 20A breaker.
10/3 copper is pointless, since you can get 2-2-2-4 aluminum feeder for the same price.  That is 90A.
#1 aluminum is 100A.
#1/0 aluminum is 120A, but they don't sell 120A breakers so you use a 125A breaker.